# RubyMotion >> How do I Cast a Variable as a Particular Type?

Tags: ios, types, casting, nsmutableurlrequest, rubymotion

Since RubyMotion appears to do a lot of type-conversion at compile-time, I'm having trouble passing in a proper dataType into a NSMutableURLRequest POST request.  It's expecting NSData, but I can't figure out how to type an NSString variable to NSData without throwing an error.  Without typecasting, our SOAP server can't properly receive the data and I get the dreaded (and vague) "The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1" error.

**This is the problematic line:**

```
postXML = "<xml><whatever>hey</whatever></xml>"
postData = ( postXML as NSData ).dataUsingEncoding( NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true );

request = NSMutableURLRequest.alloc.init
request.setURL( NSURL.URLWithString( "https://services.sbx1.cdops.net/v4.3/SubscriberServicePox.svc/Login" ) )
request.setHTTPMethod( "POST" )

request.setValue( "application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type" )
request.setHTTPBody( postData, dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding )

theConnection = NSURLConnection.alloc.initWithRequest( request, delegate:self )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `( postXML as NSData )` should be just `postXML` with no semicolon on the end, but otherwise your code doesn't throw any errors for me, and if I inspect `request.HTTPBody`, it is a `NSConcreteMutableData` object, not a `NSString`. Which specific part of your code is throwing the error?

Comment: As far as explicit type conversions go, it appears RubyMotion handles all of that for you.

Calling a NSData method on an NSString effectively types it appropriately:

Before

loginPostXML = (loginPostXML as NSData).dataUsingEncoding( NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true );
After

loginPostXML = loginPostXML.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
A simple solution, but the type-vagueness still remains (unfortunately).

Comment: `dataUsingEncoding` is the standard way to convert an NSString to NSData. Are you saying that just using `loginPostXML.dataUsingEncoding...` does or does not fix it for you? If it does, I can add it as an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of what is going on has some holes, so let's break it down.

```
postXML = "<xml><whatever>hey</whatever></xml>"
postData = ( postXML as NSData ).dataUsingEncoding( NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true );
```

I'm not sure where you got `( postXML as NSData )` from but it is not valid and makes no sense. `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` is an Objective-C method declared on [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) not `NSData`. The correct way to call it would be like this

```
postData = postXML.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
```

Ruby motion doesn't do `type conversions` for you, Ruby does not and Objective-C does not. If you send a message to a instance of a class that does not respond to the message you send it, you will crash/raise an exception.

When you call

```
postXML.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
```

you are not doing type casting, you are sending the message `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` to an instance of `NSString`. This will cause a new completely new object (an instance of `NSData`) to be returned.

Comment: I should have been clearer; (var as Type) is a convention used in other languages and I was hoping that it would better illustrate the casting question, but yes, your explaination makes sense -- much appreciated.